# link_to does not react to :confirm =>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I did search for two days now to find out why this seemingly simple piece of javascript does not work in my Ruby on Rails app. I have the following code:

```
<%= link_to "+ nieuw verzoek", :controller => "tickets", :action => "new", :confirm => "are you sure ?" %>
```

The link works but without showing me the a popup-screen with the confirm question. And I don't know why.

Here is some info about my app files:

```
My Gemfile:
-------------

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'


group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


group :development do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'annotate'
#gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
------end gemfile-----

---------------
software versions
---------------
Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p362
---------------

-------------------
application.js
-------------------
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
---------------------

----------------------
application.html.erb
----------------------

<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>SimpleCms</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>

-----------------------
```

Jquery does work. When I create a simple:

```
<div> <a class="jq" href="#"> test </a></div>
```

or by using this:

```
<%= link_to "test",{}, :href => "#",:class => "jq" %>
```

I am able to manipulate the content of this class via Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jq').click(function() {
$('.jq').animate(
{
fontSize: '40px'    
},
5000 
);

});
});
```

But when I genereate a link via link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to "+ nieuw verzoek", :controller => "tickets", :action => "new", :confirm => "are you sure ?" %>
```

No javascript is coming into action.

Hope someone can give me some direction in solving my small problem.

Thanks!

Comment: try `link_to "+ nieuw verzoek", { :controller => "tickets", :action => "new" }, :confirm => "are you sure ?" %>`

Comment: THat easy, it did the trick and my code works now. Thanks!

Comment: @jvnill - You should have made this an answer!

Comment: what I find weird is someone posted it as an answer after 30 minutes :p

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<%= link_to "+ nieuw verzoek", {:controller => "tickets", :action => "new"}, :confirm => "are you sure ?" %>
```

Comment: Thanks! That easy and such a fast answer. It did the trick. It works now.

Comment: please tick the answer if you find useful